# How to copy text from Field1 to Field2 and hold it in Field2 after resetting Field1 in Acrobat Javascript?

Tags: javascript, acrobat

following Problem. I have a Field1 and a Field2.
How to copy the value from Field1 into Field2 (realtime is not neccessary)
and hold it in Field2 so that the value of Field2 is unchanged after resetting Field1?

I try this code:

```
var val = new Array(this.getField("Field1").value);
this.getField("Field2").value = val;
```

But after resetting Field1, Field2 is empty too.
What can i change to prevent from this?

Comment: If field two is empty before copying the data, you could test whether it is empty or not before the copy.

Comment: How are you performing the reset of Field1? And what's the purpose of the Array?